# How to determine argument from Euler’s form of complex numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

When writing the Euler’s form of a complex number ($z=r e^{i \varphi}$), we say that $r$ is the magnitude of the complex number, while $\varphi$ is its argument, but the same number can be written in infinite forms by varying the values of $r$ and $\varphi$, even after keeping $\varphi$ within the principal range, so if I am asked to find the principal argument of a complex number given in Euler’s form, then how can we surely determine it? What should be the value of $r$, so that the corresponding value of $\varphi$ is accepted as the argument?

Comment: If $r\gt0$, you can determine the argument up to a multiple of $2\pi$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner , I don't get it, can you please elaborate

Comment: Do you know Cartesian to Polar conversion?

Comment: Could you give an example of the many forms of one number for $\varphi$ in principal range?

Comment: @Tensor , yes I know

Comment: @Korf , if we have two variable representing a constant, then can we not vary both the variables to have many values?

Comment: The principle is exactly the same. Given $z = a+bi$, the argument $\varphi = \frac{b}{a}$. The quadrant is determined the sign of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: If $r$ and $\varphi$ are allowed to have **complex** values then yes, you can write the same complex number in infinitely many ways. (The same goes for $a+bi$ if $a$ and $b$ can be complex numbers.) This ambiguity is avoided by restricting $a,b,r,\varphi$ to be **real** numbers, and $r$ to be nonnegative.

Comment: Of course, @Tensor meant $\tan\varphi=\frac{b}{a}$, [or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) $\varphi=\operatorname{atan2}(b,\,a)$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z = a + bi$ then we have

$$\begin{eqnarray} a + bi & = & r e^{i \varphi} \\
& = & r \left(\cos \varphi + i \sin \varphi \right) \\
\implies a & = & r \cos \varphi \\
\mbox{and } b & = & r \sin \varphi \\
\implies a^2 + b^2 & = & r^2 \end{eqnarray}$$

So for any $a, b$ there is only one possible value for $r$ in the range $[0, \infty)$. Once $r$ is known, then unless it is equal to zero the equations $\cos \varphi = \frac{a}{r}$ and $\sin \varphi = \frac{b}{r}$ only allow one value of $\phi$, up to a multiple of $2 \pi$, i.e. you will find a unique primary argument.

Answer (score 2):

For a same specific complex number, changing $r$ will change the number. You can only maintain the number constant by changing its argument (by adding $2 \pi k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$)

Changing $r$ will change the distance of the number to the origin, while changing $\theta$ will simply rotate the number. This is why $\theta$ and $\theta + 2 \pi k$ can represent the same number, it just did a complete rotation along the Argand-Gauss plane.

So, given a complex number in Euler's form $z = re^{i \theta}$, the possible arguments will simply just be $\theta + 2 \pi k$, or if you want only the principal one, use its value in the range $[0,2 \pi [$.

In general, the problems that ask to determine the argument of a given complex number will define a range for the answer, so I think there is no reason to worry about this. I hope that I helped you :)

Comment: Can a given complex number be written in only one specific value of r, when writing it in the type re^iø, if we restrict ø to (-π,π] ?

Comment: If you restrict the argument domain to $[ - \pi, \ \pi]$, then each complex number will be only able to be written in one unique specific way. But, again, that's because of the argument. Independent of the argument, you can only represent a specific complex number with only one unique value of $r$. Imagine the Argand-Gauss plane: changing $r$ will increase/decrease (without rotating) the length of the distance between your complex number $z$ and the origin. While, changing the argument will simply rotate number. You can make a direct analogy of this with vectors.

Comment: Got it, thanks.